# constructing a list of lists in python 3.0 inside a class

Tags: python, class, init

This is my code:

```
class Matrix:
    def  __init__(self,L1):
        L=[]
        for i in L1:
            self.L.append(i)
m = Matrix([[1, 2], [13, 4], [5, 6]])

print(m)
```

always get the following error, I don't know how to fix it:

```
<ipython-input-40-bb793667b807> in __init__(self, L1)
      3         L=[]
      4         for i in L1:
----> 5             self.L.append(i)
AttributeError: 'Matrix' object has no attribute 'L'
```

Comment: Do `self.L=[]` it needs to be an instance object

Comment: FYI it seems like you just want `self.L = list(L1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually assign `L` as an attribute of the object, it is just a temporary variable in your init function as you have it currently written.

Try using:

```
class Matrix:
    def  __init__(self, L1):
        self.L=[]
        for i in L1:
            self.L.append(i)
```